# How to pass a JSON to checkbox

Tags: php, html, json

Json

```
{"segment":"Class I-V Tuition,Class VI-VIII Tuition"
 ,"Board":["cbse"]
 ,"Class I-V":["Allsubject"]
 ,"Class VI-VIII":["cbse","cse/Ise"]
 ,"Class VI-VIII Subject":["Allsubject","Science"]
 ,"Class XI-X":null
 ,"Class XI-X Subject":null
 ,"Class XI-XII":null
 ,"Class XI-XII Subject":null
 ,"Languagesubject":null
 ,"engineering":null
 ,"Diploma":null
 ,"Dancesubject":null
 ,"Degree Course":null
 ,"Degree Subject":null
}

Here  key:Board
      value:cbse
      key:Class I-V
      value:Allsubject like wise json pattern stored in classconducted column
```

My questions are:

1. How to retrieve the json string?
2. I have tried like this.

   ```
   $sqledit = mysql_query("select * from  tinfo where tsname='" .$_SESSION['tutorname'] ."'");
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($sqledit); 
   foreach (json_decode($row['classconducted'], true) as $key => $val) {
      if($key!='' && $val!='') {
         echo '<span class="details">'.$key.'</span>'.': '."<br/><br/>";
         if (is_array($val))
           echo implode(',', $val) . "<br/><br/>";
         else
           echo $val . "<br/>";
       }
   }
   ```

Now I want to edit the page. So using `foreach` I separate the values. Here I have decode the json values. now the values are coming . I want to know how to pass the json values to my form. Here is my form. I have tried like this, I don't know what is wrong in my code.

**I want ouptut like this:** check this is this correct

```
<input type="checkbox" name="board[]"  value="cbse" <?php if($val[0]=='cbse'){echo "checked";}?>>CBSE
<input type="checkbox" name="board[]"  value="cse/Ise" <?php if($val[1]=='ICSE/ISE'){echo "checked";}?>>ICSE/ISE.
```

Comment: Can you better format the code above ?

Comment: DACros  I think You understood the concept here also.just I want to pass the json value to my checkbox . if the values are there I want to show  checkbox   selected.

Answer (score 0):

You do the same as in [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427491/how-to-use-if-conditon-after-explode-the-data-from-database), but parse the JSON instead of exploding it.

```
$cats = json_decode($row['classconducted'], true);

<input type="checkbox" name="segment[]" value="Class I-V Tuition" <?php if(in_array('Class I-V Tuition', $cats)) { echo "checked"; }?>> Class I-V Tuition
```

Comment: NOt coming, please check this I have done like this $cats = json_decode($row['classconducted'], true);<input type="checkbox" name="board[]"  value="cbse"<?php if(in_array('cbse', $cats)) { echo "checked"; }?>>CBSE

Comment: You're going to have to be more clear. What is the `var_dump` of `$row`? What does `$cats` print out as? You seem to be just trying bits of code, you need to know what you're working with first (and so do we).

Comment: Yes your are wright $row gives Array
(
    [segment] => Class I-V Tuition,Class VI-VIII Tuition,Class IX-X Tuition,Class XI-XII Tuition,Engineering Subjects
    [Board] => Array
        (
            [0] => cbse
        )

    [Class I-V] => Array
        (
            [0] => Allsubject
        )

    [Class VI-VIII] => Array
        (
            [0] => cbse
        )

    [Class VI-VIII Subject] => Array
        (
            [0] => Allsubject
        )

Comment: After print_r($row) I have tired like this <input type="checkbox" name="board[]"  value="cbse"<?php if($cats[0]=='cbse') {  echo "hi"; echo "checked"; }?>>CBSE  but no solutions.

Comment: DACrossby Thanks for  your knowledge. did you find any way how to solve that.In my earlier command  I have given what I have tried.

Comment: `$row` doesn't appear to have any JSON in it. Do the same as [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29427491/how-to-use-if-conditon-after-explode-the-data-from-database).