# How to use if conditon after explode the data from database

Tags: php

In my database *Class I-V Tuition*, *Class VI-VIII Tuition*, *Engineering Subject* storing values like this may be three or five or eight for example. I have listed three. After exploding `$row['commonsegment']`, how can I put an `if` condition?

```
$sqledit=mysql_query("select * from  tinfo where tsname='".$_SESSION['tutorname']."'");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($sqledit);
$segment = '';
$cats = explode(",", $row['commonsegment']);
foreach($cats as $cat) {
    $segment .= "<category>" . $cat . "</category>\n";
}
echo $segment;
```

**My db structure:**

1. commonsegement.
2. Class I-V Tuition, Class VI-VIII Tuition, Engineering Subjects
3. Dance, Class I-V Tuition, Class VI-VIII Tuition, Engineering Subjects

**I want it like this:**

```
<?php if($segment=='Class I-V Tuition'){echo "checked";}?>
<?php if($segment=='Class VI-VIII Tuition'){echo "checked";}?>
<?php if($segment=='Engineering Subject'){echo "checked";}?>
```

Comment: can you post your database structure with some data..

Comment: Thanks you can see my question.I updated my db strucuture

Comment: Before doing anything else, read into prepared statements. Your current SQL statement is very vulnerable and bound to get your database exploited.

Comment: OK I will do that I will make the necessary steps. can you give me a answer . I think you got my concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make an `if` conditional just like anywhere else.

```
$cats = explode(",", $row['commonsegment']);

foreach($cats as $cat) {
   if ($cat == "Class I-V Tuition"){
      // do stuff for the "Class I-V Tuition" category

   } else if ($cat == "Engineering Subject"){
      // do stuff for the "Engineering Subject" category

   } else {
      // do stuff for anything else

   }
}
```

**Edit**

Seems like you don't need a `foreach` loop at all - you're just checking if a value is in the database results.

```
$cats = explode(",", $row['commonsegment']);

<input type="checkbox" name="segment[]" value="Class I-V Tuition" <?php if(in_array('Class I-V Tuition', $cats)) { echo "checked"; }?>> Class I-V Tuition
```

You may want to `explode` on `", "` since your database seems to separate with comma+space, not just a comma.

Comment: Thanks I have code like this <input type="checkbox" name="segment[]"  value="Class I-V Tuition"  <?php if($cat=='Class I-V Tuition'){echo "checked";}?>>Class I-V Tuition
                    <input type="checkbox" name="segment[]"  value="Class VI-VIII Tuition" <?php if($cat=='Class VI-VIII Tuition'){echo "checked";}?>>Class VI-VIII Tuition <br/><br/> if i put this thing in foreach, it executes two times  any idea, my form is outside foreach, I should not bring the form inside foreach

Comment: I should not bring the form in foreach. I have to pass the $cat to my forms. I hope you understand

Comment: You should post this in your actual question so it's more clear what you're trying to do. Parsing code in comments is a pain. I've updated my answer, hopefully solving your issue.

Comment: Great. THanks lot I need another help from you . Yesterday I have asked this question. I did not get the solution, I felt you can do this  just see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29416581/how-to-pass-a-json-to-checkbox?noredirect=1#comment47005621_29416581 if you can . this is the great help for me and thanks lot for stack.